# I'd like to get and print records that only apply to the desired values within the list

Tags: apex, list

`List<OpportunityTeamMember> opListId = [SELECT OpportunityId, UserEmail__c, id FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId IN :opId ];`

I want to extract only records that meet the desired value from the variable. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the list and if the record meets the condition then print it, or save for later use.

```
List<OpportunityTeamMember> opListId = [SELECT OpportunityId, UserEmail__c, id FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId IN :opId ];
for (OpportunityTeamMember opportunityTeamMember : opListId) {
    if (**your condition**) {
        System.debug(opportunityTeamMember);
    }
}
```